# How to do Motivation Reaction Unit when there is multiple motivation at the same time?

Tags: technique

How to do Motivation Reaction Unit when there is multiple motivation and the main character have each reaction for each motivation.

example:
main character had an accident.

he feels the cold of the asphalt -> is the asphalt always as cold as this?

he feels sore on his head -> the pain is too strong for me to think

he see a lot of blood on the road -> am i going to die?

those are the motivation and reaction. How to write it if the character feel it at he same time?

Comment: Try a conjunction like "and" to show these things are concurrent. https://www.grammarly.com/blog/conjunctions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the motivations in your question seem to be closely related aspects of the same incident, namely the accident. Writing, as opposed to video, is inherently linear. Rather than try to deal with all of these aspects at the same time, take each of them in turn.

For example, the MC is most likely to recognize the various aspects in a sequence.

First, the pain and shock of the accident leads to dismay and fear. *"What just happened?"*

Second, as the MC comes to terms with the pain, they try to stand up and experience the cold of the ground. *"Odd, that the ground is so cold."*

Third, as the MC becomes more aware, they realize that they had placed their hand in a pool of blood as they had tried to get up. *"So much blood. Am I going to die here on this cold ground? How stupid is that?"*

Almost everyone has experienced some kind of trauma that has required multiple steps to recover from. Properly handled, the succession of experiences (motivation followed by reaction) should draw the reader into the scene.

With few exceptions, most of us handle things in sequences rather than multiple, overlapping perceptions. Writing should typically follow along.